# How to merge two dataframes In R with different names

Tags: r

Im merging two dataframes nobel_winners & nobel_winner_all_pubs. They  have "categories" in common and "year" in common however years are named different. Called Prize_year for nobel_winners whereas pub_year for nobel_winner_all_pubs. For the new merged dataframe i would like it to have the variables  "category" & "pub_year" with the latter including prize_year data from the nobel_winner data.

```
NobelMerge <-merge(x = nobel_winners, y = nobel_winner_all_pubs, by.x = "prize_year_in_nobel_winner", by.y = "pub_year_in_nobel_winner_all_pubs")
```

is my code completely off? i'm a newbie so if someone could write up the proper code it would seriously be appreciated.

Error message

```
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `by.x` and `by.y` instead of using comma? Have a look at [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/merge) .

Comment: @maydin i'm at the stage where i'm trying heaps of things. got the error both ways but thanks

Comment: The error tells that you have a problem with the column name. Check for the colnames. I have post a link above by the way. And, if you share a sample data, it can be easier to help you.

Comment: I think you need to change `by.x` and `by.y` like this: `NobelMerge <-merge(x = nobel_winners, y = nobel_winner_all_pubs, by.x = "Prize_year", by.y = "pub_year")` so that they match column names and not full datasets.